# Varios problemas con lxml xpath y excel

Tags: html, xml, xpath

quisiera saber cómo puedo agregar una condición a xpath, mi código es el de abajo. Al correrlo hay veces que no me arroja el resultado de el número de plantas ('plantas') ya que algún anuncio no tiene un valor en 'terreno'. Por eso quiero agregar la condición de que si no existe valor en terreno que aún asi me ponga el dato de plantas O que si existe un dato en plantas me lo ponga.
Y también me sucede lo mismo pero con la variable 'Fecha de Publicación'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import xlsxwriter

# Crear archivo de excel y un worksheet --> SE DEBE CAMBIAR EL NOMBRE CADA VEZ QUE HAGAS UNA NUEVA BASE DE DATOS
workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('Venta Casas.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Para tener formato bold cuando se pida
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})

# Crear los títulos de cada columna
worksheet.write('A1', 'Plantas', bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'Terreno', bold)
worksheet.write('C1', 'Recamaras', bold)
worksheet.write('D1', 'Baños', bold)
worksheet.write('E1', 'Construcción', bold)
worksheet.write('F1', 'Fecha Publicación', bold)

# Empezar desde el primer renglón debajo de los títulos
row=1
col=0
sigrowplanta=0
sigrowterreno=0
sigrowrecamara=0
sigrowbano=0
sigrowcons=0
sigrowpubl=0

numeropagina=1
# Para ir cambiando de página --> SE DEBE REVISAR LA PÁGINA MÁXIMA PARA CAMBIARLE EN EL LOOP Y SERÍA +1
while numeropagina<67:
    strnumeropagina=str(numeropagina)
    link = 'https://www.avisosdeocasion.com/Resultados-Inmuebles.aspx?n=venta-casas-nuevo-leon&PlazaBusqueda=2&Plaza=2&pagina=strnumeropagina&idinmueble=3&pagfinal=24&paginicial=1&Mosaico=0&scl=0'
    pagina=link.replace('strnumeropagina',strnumeropagina) # Para que cambie el número de la página
    page = requests.get(pagina)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    print(pagina)

    # Para sacar el número de plantas
    plantas = tree.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"planta")]/td[1]/text() or //td[contains(text(),"terreno")]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/text()')
    print('PLANTAS 1:',plantas)
    plantas2=[]
    for item in plantas:
        if not item.strip():
            item='0 plantas'
            plantas2.append(item)
        else:
            plantas2.append(item.strip())
    print('PLANTAS 2:',plantas2)
    plantas3=[]
    for casa in plantas2:
        if len(casa)<1: continue
        plantas3.append(float(casa.split()[0]))

        for datoplanta in plantas3:
            worksheet.write_number(row + sigrowplanta, col, datoplanta)
            sigrowplanta = sigrowplanta + 1

    print(len(plantas3), 'Plantas:',plantas3)

    # Para sacar los m2 del terreno
    terreno=tree.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"planta")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()')
    terreno2=[]
    for item in terreno:
        if not item.strip():
            item='0m² terreno'
            terreno2.append(item)
        else:
            terreno2.append(item.strip())
    terreno3=[]
    for casa in terreno2:
        if len(casa)<1: continue
        terreno3.append(float(casa.split('m²')[0]))

        for datoterreno in terreno3:
            worksheet.write_number(row + sigrowterreno, col+1, datoterreno)
            sigrowterreno = sigrowterreno + 1

    print(len(terreno3),'m2 Terreno:',terreno3)

    # Para sacar el número de recámaras
    recamara=tree.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"zona")]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/text()')
    recamara2=[]
    for item in recamara:
        if not item.strip():
            item='0 recamaras'
            recamara2.append(item)
        else:
            recamara2.append(item.strip())
    recamara3=[]
    for casa in recamara2:
        if len(casa)<1: continue
        recamara3.append(float(casa.split()[0]))

        for datorecamara in recamara3:
            worksheet.write_number(row + sigrowrecamara, col+2, datorecamara)
            sigrowrecamara = sigrowrecamara + 1

    print(len(recamara3), 'Recámaras:',recamara3)

    # Para sacar la zona PENDIENTE

    # Para sacar el número de baños
    bano=tree.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Nuevo León")]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/text()')
    bano2=[]
    for item in bano:
        if not item.strip():
            item='0 baños'
            bano2.append(item)
        else:
            bano2.append(item.strip())
    bano3=[]
    for casa in bano2:
        if len(casa)<1: continue
        bano3.append(float(casa.split()[0]))

        for datobano in bano3:
            worksheet.write_number(row + sigrowbano, col+3, datobano)
            sigrowbano = sigrowbano + 1

    print(len(bano3),'Baños:',bano3)

    # Para sacar los m2 de construcción
    cons=tree.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Publ")]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/text()')
    cons2=[]
    for item in cons:
        if not item.strip():
            item='0m² constr.'
            cons2.append(item)
        else:
            cons2.append(item.strip())
    cons3=[]
    for casa in cons2:
        if len(casa)<1: continue
        cons3.append(float(casa.split('m²')[0]))

        for datocons in cons3:
            worksheet.write_number(row + sigrowcons, col + 4, datocons)
            sigrowcons = sigrowcons + 1

    print(len(cons3),'m2 Construcción:',cons3)

    # Para sacar la fecha de Publicación
    publ=tree.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"constr.")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()')
    publ2=[]
    for item in publ:
        if not item.strip():
            item='Publ: 1\xa0Ene'
            publ2.append(item)
        else:
            publ2.append(item.strip())
    publ3=[]
    for casa in publ2:
        if len(casa)<1: continue
        publ3.append(casa.replace('\xa0',' ').replace('Publ:','').strip())

        for datopubl in publ3:
            worksheet.write_string(row + sigrowpubl, col + 5, datopubl)
            sigrowpubl = sigrowpubl + 1

    print(len(publ3), 'Fecha Publicado:',publ3)

    if len(plantas3)==len(terreno3)==len(bano3)==len(cons3)==len(publ3)==len(recamara3):
        print('\033[1m'+'\033[91m'+'IGUAL LAS CANTIDADES POR CATEGORÍA'+'\033[0m')

    numeropagina=numeropagina+1

workbook.close()
```

Y también quisiera saber por qué al pasar los datos a excel me copia más datos de los que existen en la página.

FUENTE DE DATOS: https://www.avisosdeocasion.com/Resultados-Inmuebles.aspx?n=venta-casas-nuevo-leon&PlazaBusqueda=2&Plaza=2&pagina=1&idinmueble=3&pagfinal=24&paginicial=1&Mosaico=0&scl=0

Comment: Por lo que he entendido tu duda es que la consulta XPATH que estas asignando no te extrae los datos que tu quieres o te faltan mas datos?

Comment: Me faltan, por ejemplo, en la página 29 no me sale el dato del número de plantas porque no trae dato el número de m2 del terreno.